# CSS Positioning of Google Translate

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to place my google translate select dropdown perfectly in my navbar but am running into a css issue which is messing up all of my dropdowns. I am trying to get my select button to be where the link RIGHT HERE is located in my fiddle. Will someone please tell me what I may need to adjust in my css?

http://jsfiddle.net/bobrierton/5c1vbo2s/

```
<!-- Nav Bar Right Block -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-border-bottom navbar-right">
                    <li id="google_translate_element" class="dropdown dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">

                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">RIGHT HERE
                            </a>
                        </li>


                        <!--<li class="no-border">
                            <i class="search fa fa-search search-btn"></i>
                            <div class="search-open">
                                <div class="input-group animated fadeInDown">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn-u" type="button">Go</button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                        </li>-->
                    </ul>
                    <!-- End Nav Bar Right Block -->
                </div><!--/end container-->
            </div><!--/navbar-collapse-->
        </div>            
        <!-- End Navbar -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout}, 'google_translate_element');
            }
        </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this CSS (**Updated**):

```
.skiptranslate.goog-te-gadget, .skiptranslate.goog-te-gadget > div{
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is the updated, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5c1vbo2s/7/), hope you are looking for this.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the above problem which you are stating?, change the **display** attribute's value to **inline-block**. Let me know if it works.

Comment: The JSFiddle which you shared, is different from the image which you posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97413/discussion-between-sahil-and-david-brierton).

Comment: It is happening because, you have used the class **navbar-right**, for **Nav Bar Right Block**, which floats google translate menu to right.

Comment: As I do not have the complete CSS of the page, you can try removing **navbar-right** class from **ul** tag.